# Few Questions on IBM Rational Functional Tester (RFT)

Tags: rft, ibm-rational

1. How to integrate RFT with Testing Environments?
2. Is there a way, that I can store all the test assets inside the RFT instead of on the PC?
3. Does RFT has version control capabilities?
4. Does RFT has ability to handle minor UI changes?
5. Can we use RFT to operate across different applications? (for e.g. If I am in a webbrowser, can I include another action from another application)
6. Does RFT has ability to link different modules to create a long end to end script? (Like keywords or functions or merging different scripts)

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: That are a lot of questions in one question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 1):

1. You setup RFT, "enable" environments on your system and start recording your first script.
2. Use ClearCase to store them on a shared place.
3. Yes, but only ClearCase is supported.
4. Yes, it has an object recognition algorithm, which gives test objects (objects on the application under test-AUT) some recognition scores. This score determines if an object is eligible or not. Minor changes in AUT affect this score a little, which does not break script execution.

5.6. Yes.

Comment: We are not using clear case, can we use Rational Team Concert (RTC) to store them on a shared place.Also, can we use RTC for versioning.

Comment: Can we store the test assets inside the RFT without using clear case?

Comment: Documentation says you can: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/c_rft_rtc_integration.html

If you don't need versioning and team collaboration, you don't have to use any SCM product; you can store all assets in RFT.

Answer (score 0):

well this is very common problem that can be resolved using data driven frame work, use xml to read the data and to print the result as well, copy ur workspace in any location will save ur data but the limitation is that u may not be able to select individual test case using this frame work, for that we have made a java based GUI tool which allows end user to run single test case also,if u want u can try this.